# Win32/Win API C++ Dialog Box is not showing

Tags: c++, winapi

I just started to learn how to use win api(But i do know basics of c++ and c#)
I had this problem with and without using window
(I'm not using DialogBar)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

INT_PTR CALLBACK Dialog(HWND dlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lparam);
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case IDH_OK:
        EndDialog(dlg, LOWORD(wparam));

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wparam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wparam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(dlg, LOWORD(wparam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
int main()
{
    DialogBoxW(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), nullptr, Dialog);
    return 0;
}
```

Update:
 1. This is console application(I forgot to say about that)
 2. Visible is true for dialog box
I didn't know what to show from .rc file

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,170,144,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,252,155,50,14
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME,59,41,20,20
    CONTROL         "Radio1",IDC_RADIO1,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,37,71,38,10
    CONTROL         "",IDC_SLIDER1,"msctls_trackbar32",TBS_BOTH | TBS_NOTICKS | WS_TABSTOP,148,108,100,15
    CONTROL         "",IDC_IPADDRESS1,"SysIPAddress32",WS_TABSTOP,127,55,100,15
    CONTROL         "",IDC_MFCSHELLTREE1,"MfcShellTree",WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,148,7,138,132
    CONTROL         "",IDC_NETADDRESS1,"msctls_netaddress",ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,7,98,70,14,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    CONTROL         "",IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1,"SysDateTimePick32",DTS_RIGHTALIGN | DTS_UPDOWN | WS_TABSTOP | 0x8,30,116,100,15
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 302
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 169
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog Info
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DLGINIT
BEGIN
    IDC_MFCSHELLTREE1, 0x37c, 88, 0
0x4d3c, 0x4346, 0x6853, 0x6c65, 0x546c, 0x6572, 0x4365, 0x7274, 0x5f6c, 
0x6e45, 0x6261, 0x656c, 0x6853, 0x6c65, 0x436c, 0x6e6f, 0x6574, 0x7478, 
0x654d, 0x756e, 0x463e, 0x4c41, 0x4553, 0x2f3c, 0x464d, 0x5343, 0x6568, 
0x6c6c, 0x7254, 0x6565, 0x7443, 0x6c72, 0x455f, 0x616e, 0x6c62, 0x5365, 
0x6568, 0x6c6c, 0x6f43, 0x746e, 0x7865, 0x4d74, 0x6e65, 0x3e75, 
    0
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_DIALOG1 AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END

#endif    // Russian (Russia) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOGBAR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 330, 16
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_CHILD
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "TODO: layout dialog bar",IDC_STATIC,126,4,77,8
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOGBAR, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 6
        RIGHTMARGIN, 323
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 9
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

The dialog box is just bunch of different things that i want to use later

Comment: Do you have the corresponding resource `IDD_DIALOGBAR`? Why you have `main` instead of `WinMain` - maybe the project is not Win32 but console or other? PS: See compiler warnings.

Comment: @i486: You can display a dialog from an application targeting the CONSOLE subsystem just as well. Using `main` is fine, as long as it uses one of the allowed signatures (this one doesn't).

Comment: That's a modal dialog box. You can use this Windows style: ``WS_VISIBLE`` by editing your resource template file or via properties panel: set ``Visible`` to ``True``

Comment: @Asesh There is no info that `WS_VISIBLE` is missing.

Comment: @i486 By default modal dialog box won't have that attribute. I just tested it.

Comment: @Asesh `WS_VISIBLE` is attribute in the resource file and we don't see it. I guess it is completely missing.

Comment: @i486 ya I just created a modal dialog box and set ``visibility`` to True and it set that attribute in the rc file

Comment: @i486 agree with your first comment, his main entry point should be ``WinMain`` instead of ``main``

Comment: @Asesh You talk about IDE and automatic edition of resource. At compile time it is important whether `WS_VISIBLE` is added and not the way you created the .RC file.

Comment: ya, thanks. I will remove my answer

Comment: @Metal Cat Please add contents of resource file (.rc) or create such file with dialog box description.

Comment: @Asesh: The only difference between using the user-defined entry points `WinMain` and `main` is, that the system allocates a console in the latter case (assuming a default configuration). In context of this question, it doesn't make a single difference either way. Why do you then propose, that the OP uses one entry point over another? Besides, there is nothing in the resource script, that identifies a modal dialog. Modality is implemented in code, not the dialog template resource.

Comment: There is no `WS_VISIBLE` in the resource file for `IDD_DIALOGBAR`. Or are you trying to show `IDD_DIALOG1`? Also, you should have a look at the return value from `DialogBoxW` and call `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @IInspectable``DialogBox`` creates a modal dialog box. If he uses ``main`` as the entry point then you do realize that a console window will also show up, that's why I told him to use ``WinMain``. Not sure, if that was his intention

Comment: @IInspectable , but what is the right signature for the console application?

Comment: @MetalCat ``int main()``, you can leave the first parameter of ``DialogBoxW`` as-is.

Comment: The `case IDH_OK` label causes the dialog to be destroyed. We do not know, what `IDH_OK` is, but it could very well coincide with a message posted or sent to the dialog procedure during normal operation. Set a breakpoint on the `EndDialog` call, and see, when it is hit. (It's also missing a `break;` statement, as your compiler warned you.) @Asesh: The dialog will always be created in front of the console window. Changing the subsystem doesn't change anything.

Comment: @IInspectable it is not hitting EndDialog() if i add "default" it will use it, instead of smth else

Comment: Correct, there is no `default` label either, as your compiler warned you about. You are simply ignoring messages sent to your dialog procedure during construction, returning indeterminate values. This isn't going to end well, as I'm sure you are well aware of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several of your controls in your dialog template are "common controls" and you need to call `InitCommonControls[Ex]` first before you can use them. `MfcShellTree` is a MFC class and can only be used in MFC applications.

Add the `DS_NOFAILCREATE` style [to force the dialog to be created](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050331-00/?p=36003) even if some of the child controls could not be created. You should also add `WS_VISIBLE`.

`IDH_OK` could be a problem if it is < `WM_APP` but you don't show where it is defined so I don't know. It is certainly missing a `break;` in the dialog procedure though.

Finally, you should check the return value from `DialogBoxW`, if it is 0 or -1 you should call `GetLastError` to find out why it failed...

Comment: GetLastError() returns 0

Comment: Thanks dude, you helped me a lot The problem was using of MFC  controls

Comment: [DialogBoxW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxw) has no return but GetLastError works.

Comment: @Laurie MSDN is wrong, check the real header files.